# Errors while JAXB classes from xsd that has other xsd imports within

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, network-protocols

I tried to generate JAXB classes for [this xsd](https://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-4.xsd) which imports another xsd by its url, and similarly the import runs into 2 levels internally. **i.e** this xsd namely **cwmp-1-4.xsd** imports its previous version **cwmp-1-3.xsd** and that imports **cwmp-1-2.xsd**.

**Attempted Solution 1 :**

The command i tried to generate jaxb classes is

```
$ xjc http://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-4.xsd -httpproxy 192.168.100.100:3128
```

And the error i got is

```
[ERROR] White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
  line 1 of http://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-4.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

**Attempted Solution 2 :**

Then i tried downloading all the xsds (including the ones that's imported internally) and replaced all import locations from "http://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-3.xsd" to "cwmp-1-3.xsd" and "http://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-2.xsd" to "cwmp-1-2.xsd", so that no dependency is looked for, in the internet and executed the below command

```
$ xjc cwmp-1-4.xsd -httpproxy 192.168.100.100:3128
```

and the error trace i got is

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-2,SessionTimeout'.
  line 103 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-3.xsd

[ERROR] cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'false' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0|1' for type '#AnonType_mustUnderstand'.
  line 107 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-3.xsd

[ERROR] a-props-correct.2: Invalid value constraint value '0' in attribute 'mustUnderstand'.
  line 107 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-3.xsd

[ERROR] cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'true' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0|1' for type '#AnonType_mustUnderstand'.
  line 88 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-2.xsd

[ERROR] a-props-correct.2: Invalid value constraint value '1' in attribute 'mustUnderstand'.
  line 88 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-2.xsd

[ERROR] cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'true' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0|1' for type '#AnonType_mustUnderstand'.
  line 98 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-2.xsd

[ERROR] a-props-correct.2: Invalid value constraint value '1' in attribute 'mustUnderstand'.
  line 98 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-2.xsd

[ERROR] cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'false' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0|1' for type '#AnonType_mustUnderstand'.
  line 107 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-3.xsd

[ERROR] a-props-correct.2: Invalid value constraint value '0' in attribute 'mustUnderstand'.
  line 107 of file:/home/vivek/TR069/cwmp/cwmp-1-3.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

**Attempted Solution 3 :**

Then tried the same with no validation option

```
$ xjc  cwmp-1-4.xsd -httpproxy 192.168.100.100:3128 -nv
```

Finally i was able to generate jaxb classes for the xsd.

**Now my questions and doubts are**

- Why am i not able to generate jaxb classes just by referring it on the internet? I am sure that there's no problem in my network pathway?
- What are the errors on attemted solution 2 and why they appeared when working with the standard protocol definition schema?
- With No Validation option i could generate the classes but i am not sure whether i will have any problems in future when marshaling and unmarshalling xmls with this generated classes?
- And i am unable to specify the package name option (-P option) as it says  classes that are already in use (this question is a least priority one)

Kindly anyone clarify me. Thanks for your great support and patience in reading this big post.. :)

***XSDs' for refernce***

- https://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-4.xsd
- https://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-3.xsd (the browser page will be empty but if you save the file you'll see the content)
- https://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-2.xsd

**Note :** Kindly save the file with .xsd extension to see the content

Comment: Have you submitted these XSD to a schema validator ? My guess (about attempt 2) is that schemas *are* not valid.

Comment: Hi Gael, i have not done that. Is it possible to validate xsd? bcoz i know to validate xml against xsd, but how to validate xsd? Also one important point to be noted here is that, these xsds' are defined by Broadband Forum for a protocol definition (called tr069), so i am bit reluctant to doubt the correctness of the xsd. Kindly clarify me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the cwmp1.x.xsd to your machine and call xjc there.
However, the java files that it generated is not a guarantee work as you may expected and now I am facing the problem that you ve been concerning which the Unmarshalling seems doesn't work in cases and complain with Unexpected Node type.
I wonder if there's any similar to xjc that works with the TR069 schema